# Validate Extjs Grid column with database column & accordingly change the row color to Green or red (EXTJS 4.2.1)

Tags: grails, extjs

Hi i am using extjs version 4.2.1

I have an extjs grid which i am populating by reading data from a CSV file

here is the code

```
var store1;

Ext.onReady(function() {
    store1 = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    storeId: 'myStore1',
    pageSize: 20,
    proxy: {
         type: 'ajax',
         url:'loadGrid',
          reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
          }

    },
    fields: ['Code','Number','Labels']

}); 
 var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store1,
    stateful: false,
    layout:'fit',
    enableColumnMove: true,
    enableColumnResize:true,  

    columns: [
        {
            text : '<b>' + 'Code' + '</b>',
            width:120,
            sortable : true,
            dataIndex: 'Code',
         },
         {
             text : '<b>' + 'Serial Number' + '</b>',
             width :120,
             sortable : true,
             dataIndex: 'Number'
         },
         {
             text : '<b>' + 'Labels' + '</b>',
             width :80,
             sortable : true,
             dataIndex: 'Labels'
         },
         {
             text : '<b>' + 'ModCode' + '</b>',
             width :120,
             sortable : true,
             dataIndex: 'test1'
         },
         {
             text : '<b>' + 'Description' + '</b>',
             width :175,
             sortable : true,
             dataIndex: 'test2'
         },
         {
             text : '<b>' + 'Error' + '</b>',
             width :160,
             sortable : true,
             dataIndex: 'test3'
         }}              
    ],

    height: 350,
    width: 920,
    renderTo: 'csvGrid',
    viewConfig: {
        stripeRows: true,
        enableTextSelection:true
    }
});
store1.reload();});
```

**What i want to do **

I want to validate the grid column 'Code' against a database table column 'CustomerCode'  if it matches then i want to change the grid row to Green 
if it doesnt match the Grid column code value with the database column value i.e Code doesnt exist then i want to change the grid row to Red

How can i do this please help i am using Grails 2.1.0 & extjs 4.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Use `getRowClass` method and add different class names for rows depending on `'Code'` value. Refer the code shown below.

```
viewConfig: {    
    getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rp, ds){ 
        if(record.get('Code')=="CustomerCode"){
            return 'row-green';
        } 
        else {  
            return 'row-red';
        }
    }
},
```

**CSS**

```
.row-green{
   background-color: green;   
}
.row-red{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gilisha ! 1)Where shall i use viewConfig: in the grid panel ??2)where shall the css code be written ?? in the file or gridpanel ?? sorry for this question ! i am totally new to EXTJS :(

Comment: You are right CoderCosmo. ViewConfig should be added to the grid panel and css should be added to the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it solves one of my problem!! but how can i compare the extjs grid column value with the a database column

Comment: I think I misunderstood  your question. I thought you were asking to compare ext column cell value with a static value like 'CustomerCode' and change row color. Sorry I don't know an answer for this question.